# Deleting the simulator's realm file

Tags: realm

When working with the simulator and RealmSwift, I was wondering what the 'official' process for resetting the database is? I've deleted the default.realm file, but now my application is crashing with either "file not found" or an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the following method in `shared_realm.cpp`:

```
Group *Realm::read_group()
{
    if (!m_group) {
        m_group = &const_cast<Group&>(m_shared_group->begin_read());
    }
    return m_group;
}
```

How can I create a new Realm file? I would have thought this would happen automatically?

Comment: In my app I delete realm file on version change (mimic to Java's `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`) and it works.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to delete the app from the simulator and run it again, this will give you a brand new Realm.